# jquery css zoom icon to images with opacity

Tags: jquery, css

I like to read articles on [Here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/04/06/Add-zoom-icon-to-images-using-CSS-and-jQuery.aspx) for add zoom icon in image `hover` using jquery and css. i add css `opacity` in hover image. this worked when i `hover` image (mouse curser on image) but when i mouse curser on zoom icon, css opacity is hidden on image. any way to fix this for opacity image in all hover ( image + zoom icon ). Thanks

Demo in jsfiddle : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/X7N33/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the opacity while hovering the `a`, not the `img`.

```
#gallery2 a:hover img{
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

The working example of it: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/X7N33/1/

Comment: if i change this, in act, background and icon Both `opacity`. zoom icon Should not opacity.

Comment: yes, I understand. pay attention to the selector. we set the opacity to IMG, not to the span :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the `:hover` from the `img` element to the `a` element. Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/3mSLs/3/. BTW, you don't need Javascript to show/hide the icon :)

HTML code

```
<div id="gallery2">   
    <a href="http://www.imagehost.co.za/thumb-CF6F_4F945924.jpg">  
        <img src="http://www.imagehost.co.za/thumb-CF6F_4F945924.jpg" />
        <span></span>
    </a>
</div>​
```

CSS code

```
#gallery2 a span {
    background-image:url(http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/zoom_icon/zoom.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:15px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* FF4+ */
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* IE10 */
         -o-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
            transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
}

#gallery2 img {
    border: solid 1px #999;
    padding:5px;
}

/* when you hover the A element, fade the image */
#gallery2 a:hover img {
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}

/* no need for Javascript to show the span element */
#gallery2 a:hover span {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* FF4+ */
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* IE10 */
         -o-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
            transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: This Worked But without jquery fade effects. Unfortunately, its less attractive.

Comment: just restore the jQuery code in this case, or wait a minute and I'll update the CSS code =)

Comment: May I offer some [(currently webkit-only) CSS Transitioning CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3mSLs/2/)?

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are hover over the icon not the image. If you add the hover event to the icon too so when you hover over the icon the image opacity changes you should be ok.